# Octave notebook shows in Jupyter but can't connect to kernel

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, octave, oct2py

I have tried to use Octave through Jupyter(Anaconda)(NOT USING PIP) but it's not working. initially I was able to install octave using conda(fig 1[showing octave in juoyter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4JRh.png), but was keep getting getting the error "Octave-cli" not found.

so I tried to set a path in the environment(fig2) [trying to set environment variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37Wke.png)

but still the octave doesn't run Kernal. its keep giving me the error " raise OSError('OCTAVE_EXECUTABLE does not point to an octave-cli file, please see README')"

i am very new to coding. so not very good at locating problem. Any detailed help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

You have to set an environmental variable that points to the executable, like this:

```
conda env config vars set OCTAVE_EXECUTABLE=/your path goes here/octave-cli
```

Then you have to re-activate the conda environment:

```
conda activate NameOfEnvironment
```

Verify that it worked:

```
conda env config vars list
```

That's how you do it. More info here:
https://github.com/Calysto/octave_kernel

I did all that, but I still can't get Octave to work in Jupyter Notebook or Jupyter Lab...